# Can it be rewritten in a less abbreviated version?

Tags: functional-style

I am trying to understand this code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

CoefficientRules[13*r^2 - 7*r + 2, r];

f[a_, n_] := a^2 + n;

Map[Function[{x}, f[165/100, x[[1, 1]] + 1]*x[[2]]], 
 CoefficientRules[13*r^2 - 7*r + 2, r]]
```

I don't understand this part  f[165/100, x[[1, 1]] + 1]*x[[2]] , could you please explain this notation and if it's possible to rewrite this line in a less abbreviated version?

Comment: `Hold[< unknown expression >] // FullForm` will expand the short forms enough to point you to the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this makes it little more clear

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[a_, n_] := a^2 + n;
coeff = CoefficientRules[56*r^4 + 13*r^2 - 7*r + 2, r]
g[x_] := f[165/100, x[[1, 1]] + 1]*x[[2]];
(g[#] &) /@ coeff
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Could you rewrite this part ((g[#] &) /@ coeff) without #, & and /@

One way might be

```
Table[ g[coeff[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@coeff}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
 First@Last@Reap@Do[ Sow@g[coeff[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@coeff}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But whatever you do, do not use `For`.

But using `Map` (which is what `&/@` does it better and shorter.

Adding Lukas suggestion also:

```
 Map[g, coeff]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

> And I don't understand this line g[x_] := f[165/100, x[[1, 1]] +
> 1]*x[[2]], the argument x is a matrix 2X2?

`x` in this context is each entry of `coeff`. But `coeff` is

```
coeff = CoefficientRules[56*r^4 + 13*r^2 - 7*r + 2, r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So when you do Map, each `x` will be one entry in the above list. i.e. `{4} -> 56` then `{2} -> 13` then  `{1} -> -7` and so on until all entries are used in the list.   So `x` is each one of these. Let look at one of them

```
({4} -> 56)[[1, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
({4} -> 56)[[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you see what `f[165/100, x[[1, 1]] + 1]*x[[2]]` does. For this entry, it becomes  `f[165/100, 4+1]*56`

Comment: Thanks! Could you rewrite this part ((g[#] &) /@ coeff) without #, & and /@ please

Comment: @MamMam you can write `Map[g, coeff]` instead. See also [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/193)

Comment: Why is the function g[x_] in this expression written in this form g, and not as usual g[x] ?

Comment: And I don't understand this line g[x_] := f[165/100, x[[1, 1]] + 1]*x[[2]], the argument x is a matrix 2X2?

Comment: @MamMam fyi, updated

Comment: Thank you very much!